# How to view only special content of a log file?

Tags: linux, logs

Is there an easy way to truncate a big log file? Or in other words: How to view only special contents of a log file. E.g.

- How can I extract the last 1000 lines from a log file?
- How can I extract only lines with a special string in it?
- How can I extract log files with a special date/time?

I only know `tail` but this command is restricted to the last 10 lines and it is too fast. Searching in a 8 GB log file takes to much time ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I extract the last 1000 lines from a log file?

`tail -1000 file.log`

> How can I extract only lines with a special string in it?

`grep special_string file.log`

> How can I extract log files with a special date/time?

I'm not sure I understood this one, can you elaborate more? What do you need to do exactly?

Comment: Yeah, I tried the grep command, but with a 8 GB log file this doesn't work. At your last point: I want for example the log entries from 12th October 2pm to 12th October 3pm.

Comment: `grep` will work on an 8 GB log file. You may need to wait. You may need to take care how you specify your special string.

Comment: @testing: I just saw this comment. About the third thing you asked, you can definitely do it with the `find` command. The syntax depends on the machine you're on, since different Unix have different implementations. Your best bet: `man find`!

Comment: @testing: I'm assuming you mean you're looking for the log files that have been last modified in special times.

Comment: @rahmu: Yes, I look for entries in the log files and I want to constrain the set of result depending on a certain period of time. I'll look at the `find` command the next time.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I extract only lines with a special string in it?

I'll only address this one.  On Solaris or HP-UX systems `grep`, `egrep` and `fgrep` exist as seperate files, and each using a different algorithm.  Most linux distros just have GNU grep, and symbolic links to each of the 3 names. If you don't have to match a pattern with a metacharacter ('.', '*', '?', etc) in it, just match a plain string, then `fgrep` will undoubtedly run faster.  Even if `fgrep` runs faster for you, 8GB of log is an awful lot of text to process.  How about splitting it up into smaller, half-gig files?

Comment: Is there a convenient command for splitting a 8 GB file in half-gig files?

Comment: Using GNU split: `split -b 500m EightGBfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it once, use `grep` and `tail`.

Consider using `logrotate` (from a `cron` to deal with huge log files. You can configure it to split logs by time, size, number of lines etc. It's very handy and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider `logwatch` or something similar to filter out the important stuff.